# case expression only showing once

Tags: sql-server

I have a case expression that i'm having difficulty with:

```
WHEN @CustomerID = 3 AND @OrderID = 2 AND @Name IN ('Hello') THEN 'Regular'
WHEN @CustomerID = 3 AND @OrderID = 2 AND @Telephone = 1 AND @Name IN ('Hello') THEN 'Business'
```

It only returns the 'Regular' if I have two of the statements, but if I take out the 'Regular' it shows the Business one.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are your expected results?  `Case` statements will return the first it matches on.

Comment: When you write a `Case` statement, the `When` clauses need to run from "most restrictive" to "least restrictive", because (as @sgeddes points out) the first match will return.

Comment: I want to show both

Comment: You can either call the top (most restrictive, swap the current order) level `'Business-Regular'`, or something similar, or have two fields and let one say `Business` and the other say `Regular`.  A `CASE` expression won't continue past the first match.  A couple rows of sample data and expected results would clear up which you want.

Comment: `CASE` Expression (not statement). :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want either or both then it needs to be either two separate columns, or if you want a single column include both outputs in it:

Either:

```
case WHEN @CustomerID = 3 AND @OrderID = 2 AND @Name IN ('Hello') THEN 'Regular' end,
case WHEN @CustomerID = 3 AND @OrderID = 2 AND @Telephone = 1 AND @Name IN ('Hello') THEN 'Business' end
```

or:

```
WHEN @CustomerID = 3 AND @OrderID = 2 AND @Telephone = 1 AND @Name IN ('Hello') THEN 'Regular, Business' 
WHEN @CustomerID = 3 AND @OrderID = 2 AND @Name IN ('Hello') THEN 'Regular'
```

Answer (score 0):

The value that is returned will be the value of the THEN expression for the earliest WHEN clause (textually) that matches.

In your query, Second WHEN clause contains a part of First WHEN clause. That means, First WHEN Clause will be true whenever Second is true.Hence return THEN expression for the earlies (First ) WHEN Clause.

Query-1:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @CustomerID = 3 AND @OrderID = 2 AND @Name IN ('Hello') THEN 'Regular'
WHEN @CustomerID = 3 AND @OrderID = 2 AND @Telephone = 1 AND @Name IN ('Hello') THEN 'Business' END
```

Query-2:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @CustomerID = 3 AND @OrderID = 2 AND @Telephone = 1 AND @Name IN ('Hello') THEN 'Business'
WHEN @CustomerID = 3 AND @OrderID = 2  AND @Name IN ('Hello') THEN 'Regular' END
```

input:

```
@CustomerID INT=3
@OrderID INT = 2
@Name VARCHAR(100)='Hello'
@Telephone INT=1
```

output:

```
Query1 : 'Regular'
Query1 : 'Business'
```

input:

```
@CustomerID INT=3
@OrderID INT = 2
@Name VARCHAR(100)='Hello'
@Telephone INT=0
```

output:

```
Query1 : 'Regular'
Query1 : 'Regular'
```